# webdav davfs2 input/output error

Tags: linux, input, webdav, davfs2

I've got a box.com account configured in a Linux system so a user can mount it in a certain mountpoint and access its contents. It is declared in fstab as:

```
https://www.box.com/dav /media/box davfs rw,user,noauto 0 0
```

And the user that mounts the account has the ~/.davfs2/secrets with the following:

```
/media/box <username> <password>
```

The user can mount and list the mounted folder without any problem, but it gives us some problems when trying to copy files from box.com to our local machine. I've tried the following with these results:

```
cat /media/box/example_file.txt => Will output the contents of the file
cp /media/box/example_file.txt /tmp => will give the I/O error
wc -l /media/box/example_file.txt => will give the I/O error as well
touch asd && cp asd /media/box && ls /media/box => lists asd in /media/box
```

I've tried setting

```
use_locks 0
```

in /etc/davfs2/davfs2.conf but it doesn't solve the problem.

Any clue what might be preventing the system to properly access box.com mountpoint?